# Sobel edge detection on raster data in R returns lines instead of edges in r

Tags: r, convolution, lidar, sobel

I'm using the lidR, raster, and terra packages in R to perform a canopy height model (CHM) analysis on a LiDAR dataset, and I'm attempting to use Sobel edge detection on my CHM data.

```
library("lidR")
library("raster")
library(rgl)
library(RANN)
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(EBImage)


las <- readLAS("lasfile")
st_crs(las) <- 25832
lasNormal <- filter_poi(las, Classification != 2)



chm <-
  rasterize_canopy(las, res = 0.5, p2r(0.3, na.fill = NULL))
gf <- focalWeight(chm, .3, "Gauss")
chm <- focal(chm, w = gf)

# Plot the smoothed CHM in grayscale
plot(chm, col = grey.colors(255))


# Set the CRS of the raster
terra::crs(chm) <- "+init=epsg:25832"
# Convert the raster to a matrix
chm_matrix <- raster::as.matrix(chm)
chm_im <- as.cimg(chm_matrix)

conv2D <- function(img, fltr) {
  # Dimensions of image and filter
  img_dim <- dim(img)
  fltr_dim <- dim(fltr)
  
  # Padding size
  pad <- floor(fltr_dim / 2)
  
  # Add zero padding to the image
  padded_img <- matrix(0, nrow = img_dim[1] + 2 * pad[1], ncol = img_dim[2] + 2 * pad[2])
  padded_img[(pad[1] + 1):(pad[1] + img_dim[1]), (pad[2] + 1):(pad[2] + img_dim[2])] <- img
  
  # Output image
  output <- matrix(0, nrow = img_dim[1], ncol = img_dim[2])
  
  # Apply the filter
  for (i in 1:img_dim[1]) {
    for (j in 1:img_dim[2]) {
      region <- padded_img[i:(i + 2 * pad[1]), j:(j + 2 * pad[2])]
      output[i, j] <- sum(region * fltr)
    }
  }
  
  return(output)
}

# Now, use this function to compute the edge detection
sh <- matrix(c(-1, 0, 1, -2, 0, 2, -1, 0, 1), nrow = 3)
sv <- t(sh)
xh <- conv2D(chm_matrix, sh)
xv <- conv2D(chm_matrix, sv)
edge <- sqrt(xh^2 + xv^2)



edge_raster <- terra::rast(edge)

# Copy geographic information from the original raster
terra::ext(edge_raster) <- terra::ext(chm)
terra::crs(edge_raster) <- terra::crs(chm)

# Plot the raster
terra::plot(edge_raster,col = grey.colors(255))
```

However, the result I'm getting is a raster image with lines, whereas I was expecting to see edges from the edge detection process. Can someone please help me understand why I'm getting this result and how I might be able to achieve the edge detection I'm looking for?
[image: Chm]  [image]

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include some simple example data (generated with code) so that we can reproduce your results. Also, I think you could use `terra::focal` for this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the packages you are using other than `EBImage`. Perhaps the Sobel object you generated is not an `Image` object? I've extracted your example image (less axes and labels) and applied a Sobel filter function meant to return an image. Perhaps this will do what you want.

```
# Assuming EBImage has been loaded

# Sobel function
  sobel <- function (x) 
  {
    sh <- matrix(c(1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -2, -1), nrow = 3)
    sv <- t(sh)
    xh <- filter2(x, sh, boundary = "replicate")
    xv <- filter2(x, sv, boundary = "replicate")
    return(sqrt(xh^2 + xv^2))
  }

# image
  x <- readImage(file.choose()) # extracted image saved locally
  img <- abind(x, sobel(x), along = 3)
  dev.new(width = 6, height = 1.9)
  plot(img, all = TRUE)
```

[image: Raw Image and Sobel transform]